# Which tall building was completed in 1940 in Europe?

Tags: world-war-two, europe, architecture

[This chart](http://sploid.gizmodo.com/interesting-chart-shows-what-the-tallest-building-built-1700335914) from *The Economist* lists the tallest building completed each year since 1885.

It seems a tallish building (over 100m) was completed in Europe in 1940, and indeed this was the tallest building completed during that year, across the whole world.

[image]

Which building was this, and was it in a city at war in 1940 like Paris, London or Berlin? Or was it in one of the neutrals?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Terrazza Martini Tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrazza_Martini_Tower) (former name, formal name is Piacentini Tower) is a highrise building located in Genoa, Italy. Construction on the building began in 1935, and finished in 1940. It was designed by Marcello Piacentini and Angelo Invernizzi. It has 31 floors, and contains office spaces. Its roof height is 108 m, and counting its spire, the full building height is 116 m.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrazza_Martini_Tower) This building was the tallest highrise building in Europe from 1940 to 1952

Answer (score 0):

maybe look at the KBC Tower in Antwerp Belgium , this was completed around that time and was the tallest building in Europe for a period. It is still standing and was damaged in WW2

Comment: OR check out this one which replaced the building in Antwerp as tallest in 1940 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrazza_Martini_Tower

Comment: I believe you have the answer - you should move it to an answer to get credit.